# String append in linux shell script

Tags: linux, sh

I writing Linux shell script to test upload file .

before we upload file into storage system i need to get the storage url using rest full service , getting url is successful .in storage url i want to append one string .

```
Url=$(grep "X-Storage-Url" swiftAuth.txt)  //read url value from file
storageFileUrl=${storageUrl#*:}  //remove extra string before :
echo $storageFileUrl"/111"
```

url is like https://cloudstorage.com/auth/1.0

so when i trying to append string in run time it gives me wrong value 
result is :

```
/111s://cloudstorage.com/auth/1.0
```

above result is wrong i want result

```
https://cloudstorage.com/auth/1.0/111
```

Please help me

Thanks.

Comment: Try: storageFileUrl=${storageUrl#*:}/111 ?

Comment: If this is a bash script, put `#!/bin/bash -vx` on its first line (for debugging purposes) and run it again. You'll get a trace of what the shell is doing.

Comment: Also, consider using `awk` in your case. It would make the shell script shorter.  Or even make it an `awk` script

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's the same old problem.  The file from which the value is being read has `CR+LF` line endings.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not getting `/111s://cloudstorage.com/auth/1.0`. You are getting `https://cloudstorage.com/auth/1.0␍/111`.

The `␍` is carriage return, also known as Ctrl-M or `^M`.

Bash considers that a regular character. You should be able to strip it by simply `${storageFileUrl%␍}`. You can type `␍` on command-line, in vim or in emacs using combination <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd>.

Or you can use `recode` or `dos2unix` or similar tool to get rid of the ␍s in input to the initial grep.

Or you can use sed to combine the grep and stripping into one step and that can handle the ␍ for you as well (using the fact that URL can't contain whitespace):

```
storageFileUrl=$(sed -n 's/X-Storage-Url:[ \t]*\([^ \t\r]*\).*/\1/p')
```

Note: MIME specifies ␍␊ line endings for the header and Unix only uses ␊, so it's kind of expected to see the ␍s there.